# what is the functionality of `/* $Id$ */` in php-src files

Tags: php-internals

It's included in many files.

For example:

`/* $Id: php_cli.c 306938 2011-01-01 02:17:06Z felipe $ */`

Is this helping debug process or something else? Any tool related?

Comment: That is a marker that is replaced by the source control software.

Comment: This is a leftover from SVN times. These markers are not used anymore.

Comment: Found it, Thanks